# Merge multiple Flask apps together

Tags: python, flask

Given an Express inspired directory structure:

```
app.py
noun_0/
    routes.py
    models.py
noun_1/
    routes.py
    models.py
```

What do I need inside app.py to merge my two apps?

Using Bottle I could just do [`app.merge()`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.merge). What's the Flask solution?

Comment: [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/).

Comment: Yeah, I think that's right. Just implementing it together to confirm it all works.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work due to `ImportError`s, exact same structure works fine with Bottle, so will just use Bottle...

Comment: Any updates/movements on this? It would be a useful feature to merge independently composed sites.